# How to Stop scanning webcam when QR found and can make it scan again

Tags: python, qr-code, barcode-scanner, opencv

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()

    decodedObjects = pyzbar.decode(frame)
    for obj in decodedObjects:
        #print("Data", obj.data)
        cv2.putText(frame, str(obj.data), (50, 50), font, 2,
                    (255, 0, 0), 3)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and you should (re-)read the help topic [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to set your expectations. It is hard to understand what you want. Consider adding a description to your question. Don't try to write everything into the title. Describe your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can just stop showing the frame. Then use another key to continue. For example:

```py
import cv2
import pyzbar.pyzbar as zbar

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX 

stopped = False
delay = 1

while(True):
    ret = cv2.waitKey(delay) & 0xFF

    if ret == ord('c'): # continue
        stopped = False
        delay = 1

    if ret == ord('q'):
        break

    if stopped or (ret == ord('s')): # stop
        stopped = True
        delay = 30
        continue

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    decodedObjects = zbar.decode(frame)
    if len(decodedObjects) > 0:
        stopped = True
        y = 50
        for obj in decodedObjects:
            #print("Data", obj.data)
            print(obj.data.decode("utf-8"))
            cv2.putText(frame, obj.data.decode("utf-8"), (50, y), font, 2, (255, 0, 0), 3)
            y += 50

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)


# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```